# Dynamic access to oracle apex 19.2 pages

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to find a solution to create something similar to a server-side condition for pages. I want pages to be available depending on some global variables. I have created a function that returns a logical value in the database. How to implement it? I tried to use authorization schemes, but it doesn't work with parameters.

Comment: What are the "global variables" - application items?  If so then your authorization scheme can look up their values.

Comment: Depending on how you're trying to apply this, you may need to consider the authorisation scheme's "evalutation point". ie - once per session vs per page view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, value returned by that function decides whether someone is allowed to use certain page or not. You didn't explain what it exactly does, so I'll presume that it returns Boolean: `TRUE` (yes, allow page access) or `FALSE` (don't allow it), based on certain parameters such as `:APP_USER`.

If that's so, my suggestion would be to do what you already tried but failed for some reason.

- navigate to Shared Components
- go to Security - **Authorization Schemes**
- create a new scheme, let's call it `AS_ALLOW`
- set

  - scheme type = PL/SQL function returning Boolean
  - PL/SQL function body

    ```
    return your_function(:APP_USER);
    ```
  - message displayed when scheme violated: "You aren't authorized to visit this page"

Now, back to page. Open its **Security** properties and put

- `AS_ALLOW` into the "Authorization scheme"

That should do it; once the user runs the application, the function will return either `TRUE` or `FALSE` which will - in turn - allow (or not) that user's access to page that has the authorization scheme set.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot for answer. I needed to check permission no to app but to page. I needed to check if specific role has permission to specific page. So i did a authorization schema with 3 parameters :APP_ID (i have this as a paremeter in dictionary) :APP_PAGE_ID and :ROLE (application variable) and use it in security attribute in page attributes.

Comment: You're welcome. What I described does exactly that - restricts access to a **page**.